# Message written in vue function not showing on browser

Tags: php, html, laravel, vue.js

I'm new to Laravel and VueJs. 
I installed nodejs because it was the way to have the "npm" command in my prompt.

This is in my app.js inside resources/js :

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        message: 'my new msg'
    }
});
```

But it says that my const app in not used but i use it here in my welcome.blade.php:

```
 <div id="app">
            @{{ message }}
        </div>
```

i have ran the command "npm run watch" but the only thing that appears on my browser is {{message}} and not the content of the message.

Comment: It doesnt look like your vue files are being compiled correctly. Your vue project should be in a folder and web pack will compile that into a single `.js` file

Comment: any suggestions on how to fix?

Comment: I suggest you go view the [vue cli 3 tutorial](https://cli.vuejs.org/) and figure out how vue works. Vues html might look like normal html but its not.

Comment: Have you added a `<script>` tag to your Blade template somewhere, to bring in the generated JS file?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script> i have wrote this on my welcome.blade.php